# AVCapturePreviewLayer by uiviewrepresentable very slow

Tags: swiftui, camera, avfoundation, uiviewrepresentable

I'm making camera app using swiftui.

Because of performance issue, I'm trying to show preview using AVCapturePreviewLayer.

I found the way in stackoverflow and It worked.

Basically, I have a root ContentView.
when I tap button Navigation goes to CameraView.

The problem is here.
when I pop out the CameraView going back to rootView.

1. class CameraPreviewView: UIView => deinit not called.
2. When I navigate again, **it takes long time to show preview(dark screen first -> preview)**
   (and deinit is called)

What is problem???

```
class CameraPreviewView: UIView {
        
    private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession

    init(session: AVCaptureSession) {
        print("Check Point 1")
        self.captureSession = session
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }

    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        // TEST
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        var aspectRatio: CGFloat = 1.0
        
        var viewFinderHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
        var viewFinderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
        var viewFinderMarginLeft: CGFloat = 0.0
        var viewFinderMarginTop: CGFloat = 0.0
        
        aspectRatio = screenWidth / screenHeight
        viewFinderWidth = self.bounds.width * aspectRatio
        viewFinderHeight = self.bounds.height
        viewFinderMarginLeft *= aspectRatio
        
        if nil != self.superview {
            print("Check Point 2")
            self.videoPreviewLayer.session = self.captureSession
            self.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
            //Setting the videoOrientation if needed
//            self.videoPreviewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(viewFinderMarginLeft, viewFinderMarginTop, viewFinderWidth, viewFinderHeight)
            
            self.videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("Preview deinit")
    }
}
```

```
struct CameraPreviewHolder: UIViewRepresentable {
    

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CameraPreviewHolder>) -> CameraPreviewView {
        print("Check Point 3")
        return CameraPreviewView(session: captureSession)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CameraPreviewView, context: Context) {
        print("Check Point 4")
        
    }
    

    
    typealias UIViewType = CameraPreviewView
}
```

```
struct CameraView: View {

    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            CameraPreviewHolder(captureSession: CameraManager.shared.session)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            
        }
    }
        
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var title: String = "Custom Camera App"
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color("MainColor")
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        VStack {
                            Spacer()
                                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/9)
                            Text(title)
                                .font(.system(size: 35))
                                .bold()
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                        VStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: CameraView()) {
                                ZStack {
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("SubColor"))
                                        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                    Text("Camera")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .font(.body)
                                        .bold()
                                }
                            } // NavigationLink to Camera
                            
                        } // Vstack - inner
                    } // Zstack
                } // Vstack
            }
        } // NavigationView
    }
}
```

printed logs are

Check Point 3
Check Point 1
Check Point 2
Check Point 4
Check Point 3
Check Point 1
Check Point 2
Check Point 4
Preview deinit

I was trying to show preview using AVCapturePreviewLayer (UIViewRepresentable)
But I think some memory issue is coming(???)
Since First preview is rendering very fast but next time, really slow.